# Set up Webhook with call to twilio API - Sms sending

Tags: api, twilio, webhooks, postman

We are trying to set up a [webhook](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/132589-using-webhooks-in-the-observer) on freshdesk to send a sms according to a certain event.

Using postman, I'm successfully making the call to [twilio's API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and the sms is being send properly:

[image]

But I can't figure how to set up the params to that call in freshdesk:

[image]

I'm sure that the event is being triggered because the rest of the actions are happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your Freshdesk setup all looks correct except for one thing. You have the encoding set as JSON, where it should be X-FORM-ENCODED. I'd suggest switching that radio button and trying again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback.
If I do that, I can't input my variables any more, since they force the usage of theirs:
http://postimg.org/image/um3m6qpcf/

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Twilio only accepts form encoded parameters, so you might not be able to directly use the webhook with Twilio. What you could do is put together a middleman app that receives your JSON request from Freshdesk, translates it to form encoding and sends it on to Twilio.